# Product of functions in Hardy space

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $H^p(D)$ denote the Hardy space on the open unit disk in the complex plane with $0<p\le\infty$.

Consider $f\in H^r(D)$ and $g\in H^s(D)$ for $0<r,s\le\infty$.

> Does there exist a $0<t\le\infty$ s.t. $f\cdot g\in H^t(D)$ ?

*Related question:*

Let $N$ denote the Nevanlinna class, i.e. the class of holomorphic functions on the disc $f$ s.t.

$$\sup_{0\le r<1} \int_0^{2\pi} \log^+|f(re^{i\theta})| d\theta<\infty$$
where $\log^+(t)=\max\{0, \log(t)\}$ for $t>0$.

> Then for $f,g\in N$ do we know that $f\cdot g\in N$?

An answer to any of the two is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, assume that $s\leq t$; then using Jensen's inequality we get that $f,g\in H^s(D)$. We have 
$$2|f(re^{i\theta})|^{s/2}|g(re^{i\theta})|^{s/2}\leq |f(re^{i\theta})|^s+|g(re^{i\theta})|^s,$$
so $f\cdot g\in H^{t/2}(D)$ (the case $t=\infty$ is obvious).

We have $\log^+t=\frac{\log t+|\log t|}2$, so for $a,b>0$
$$\log^+(ab)=\frac{\log a+\log b+|\log a+\log b|}2\leq \log^+a+\log^+b,$$
which gives the result.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out :-). But in the inequality it should be $s$ and not $t$.

Comment: Right, fixed now.